# Laravel collection using map and contains

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having problem with `available` key in the `map` collection.

The `available` key use `contains` method. It should return true if the value of product id in $unavailableProducts does not contain in $products `($value->product_id == $product->id)`

What did I do wrong?

```
    $unavailableProducts = $this->unavailableProducts();
    $products = $this->products->all();

    $allProducts = $products->map(function ($product) use($unavailableProducts) {
    return [
        'id'            => $product->id,
        'title'         => $product->title,
        'available'     => $unavailableProducts['result']->contains(function ($value, $key) use ($product) {
            if ($value->product_id == $product->id) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }),
    ];
});
```

Comment: Are you sure `$unavailableProducts['result']` is a collection? If not, just wrap it: `collect($unavailableProducts['result'])`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, make sure that `$unavailableProductions['result']` is a collection.

Second, change your `contains` method like this:

```
$unavailableProducts = $this->unavailableProducts();
$products = $this->products->all();

$allProducts = $products->map(function ($product) use($unavailableProducts) {
    return [
        'id'            => $product->id,
        'title'         => $product->title,
        'available'     => $unavailableProducts['result']->contains('id', $product->id),
    ];
});
```

The `$unavailableProducts['result']->contains('id', $product->id)` will determine if the `$unaviableProductions['result']` collection has a key `id` where the value is `$product->id`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach

```
 $policyPackageDetails = PolicyPackage::where('isactive', '=', 1)->where('id', '=', $pid)
            ->with('policy_package_details')
            ->select('id',
                     'title',
                     'subtitle',
                     'shorttitle',
            )
            ->get();


        $policyPackageDetails = $policyPackageDetails ->map(function ($item){
            return collect([
                'id' => $item->id,
                'title' => $item->title,
                'subtitle' => $item->subtitle,
                'short_title' => $item->shorttitle,
                'policy_package_details' => $item->policy_package_details->map(function ($details){
                    return [
                        'attribute_name' => $details->attname,
                        'attribute_value' => $details->attvalue,
                    ];
                }),
            ]);
        });
```

here fetching data from relational models, remaining & filtering them, the output will be like

```
[
    {
        "id": 61,
        "title": " Health (Platinum)",
        "subtitle": "for 1 year",
        "short_title": "HL-SHP-1",
         "policy_package_details": [
            {
                "attribute_name": "in",
                "attribute_value": "180000"
            },
            {
                "attribute_name": "out",
                "attribute_value": "20000"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```