# Laravel 5.6 how to preserve float and int values in json response?

Tags: php, json, laravel

Searching about 20 minutes and still can't find reliable answer how to simply configure json respone for float type.

```
$array = DB::select('SELECT name, balance FROM ... blah blah blah'); // balance is float

return response()->json([
   'data' => $array
]);
```

It returns:

```
{"data":[
   {"name":"bob","balance":"889.37700000000018"},
   {"name":"john","balance":"705.77400000000011"}
]}
```

So, as you might guess I want to have float type in this json data for balance values:

```
{"data":[
   {"name":"bob","balance":889.37700000000018},
   {"name":"john","balance":705.77400000000011}
]}
```

I can use standard `json_encode()` function with `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION` flag to solve this issue.

But how to do the same thing with `response()->json()` ?

I've tried this sample but it fails and error occurs:

```
return response()->json([
      'data' => $array
   ],
   Response::HTTP_OK,
   [],
   JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION
);
```

Comment: "it fails and error occurs:"...what error exactly? According to the source code https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php#L24 you appear to have used the correct options.

Comment: @ADyson, sorry, I didn't capture an error. But it would be great if I could put just one flag for this purpose instead of all params in `response()->json()` function.

Comment: it if threw an error, you must be able to capture it. Otherwise what would be the purpose of throwing it? Check your logs, and/or enable PHP error reporting and then see what response you get to the request which called this script.

Comment: If you can use `Eloquent/Model` for this, you have a solution to cast your serialized model attributes by specifying it's mapping in `$casts` array.

Comment: @FarooqKhan, thanks! Is tere any example for mapping and casting specific values of the collection?

Comment: yes, let me share an answer

Comment: @FarooqKhan, I think [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43713116/5246900) can be used for casting as well. Thanks!

Comment: @mr.boris sure there are always multiple ways to acheive a solution :-)

Comment: @mr.boris if you have a solution, please write it in the Answers section...keep your question as a question and put your answer separately. This is a question-and-answer site, not a discussion forum. Please stick to the format. Then people can vote your question and your answer separately, and it's clear what the accepted solution was for future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can casts your model attributes by providing  a mapping as

```
class UserModel {

    // mention mapping to primitive data-types as [int, float, boolean, decimal, real, array, object]
    protected $casts = array(
        "is_admin" => "boolean",
        "age" => "integer",
        "salary" => "float",
        "certificates" => "array"
    );
}
```

Resulted serialized model `JSON` will be casted as per your mappings.

```
[
    {
        "is_admin": true,
        "age": 30,
        "salary":  100.12,
        "cetificates": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by sorting query result and casting balance value to float in foreach loop.

```
$array= [];

foreach($result as $row) {
   array_push($array, [
      'name' => $row->name,
      'balance' => (float) $row->balance
   ]);
}

return response()->json([
   'data' => $array
]);
```