# After I deployed laravel api on shared hosting server the Json decimal attributes are casted to string

Tags: php, laravel

Outputs 
  local Server:

```
  "rating":
    [
    {
    "userId":"M-EU-5dd65499c4cd5",
    "serviceProviderId":"SP-5dd674fd631e1",
    "rating":5,
    "created_at":"2019-11-25 14:15:28",
    "updated_at":"2019-11-25 14:15:28"
    }
    ]
```

on shared hosting server

```
  "rating":
        [
        {
        "userId":"M-EU-5dd65499c4cd5",
        "serviceProviderId":"SP-5dd674fd631e1",
        "rating":"5",
        "created_at":"2019-11-25 14:15:28",
        "updated_at":"2019-11-25 14:15:28"
        }
        ]
```

migration

```
Schema::create('s_p_ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('userId');
        $table->string('serviceProviderId');
        $table->double('rating');
        $table->primary(['userId', 'serviceProviderId']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Before I deployed it to shared hosting server it works fine. I don't know what the problem is

Comment: what was the diif in `local & live` and where is you code for get `json data`

Comment: Which PHP versions are you using in each environment?

Comment: Try the `$cast` attribute for the modal as shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277393/laravel-5-6-how-to-preserve-float-and-int-values-in-json-response

Comment: I use php version 7.1 on each enviroment

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$cast` property on each models